# ggplot2 labels won't dodge with geom_col bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I've been through related questions and those answers aren't solving my problem of labels not dodging to match the `geom_col` bars:

**Data**

```
x <- structure(
  list(capacity = c(0, 0, 0, 2.1, 3.1, 4, 4.6, 5.6, 6, 
                                 1.9, 2.3, 3.8),
       year = c("FY21", "FY21", "FY21", "FY21", "FY21",
                "FY20", "FY20", "FY20", "FY20", "FY19", "FY19", "FY19"),
       unified_date = structure(c(18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18659,
                                  18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18536,
                                  18567, 18597), class = "Date")),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Code**

```
ggplot2::ggplot(x, aes(x = unified_date, y = capacity, fill = year)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = capacity),
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            vjust = -0.5, size = 4)
```

**Chart**

[image: not-dodged ggplot]

I've tried adding `fill = year` to the `geom_text` `aes`, or `group = year`, moving `aes` values around, variants on `position_dodge()` - nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
ggplot2::ggplot(x, aes(x = factor(unified_date), y = capacity, fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = capacity),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 4,vjust=-0.5)+
  xlab('Date')
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to work with the month properly try this:

```
#Code 2
x %>% mutate(Month=format(unified_date,'%b')) %>%
  mutate(Month=factor(Month,levels = unique(Month),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = capacity, fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = capacity),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 4,vjust=-0.5)+
  xlab('Date')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: so was the underlying issue that `position_dodge()` didn't work with a Date?

Comment: @SamFirke It was because of the dates, as the scale is defined specifically for dates, you got the overlap in the labels. Adding format to dates changed everything! I hope that was clear for you!